# Turning Glassfish 3 on and off on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, glassfish

I just installed Glassfish 3. My browser shows me the Glassfish 3 Control Panel at `127.0.0.0:4848`.
Since my computer is also running the Apache2 server for my PHP development, and I don't want to use too much memory, I want to be able to turn Glassfish on or off at will. e.g. if I want to turn the Apache2 server off on my Ubuntu machine I use the command
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache stop`

So what is the procedure to turn the Glassfish server off on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to the glassfish/bin directory

Run the following as needed:

- asadmin start-domain domain1
- asadmin stop-domain domain1

Visit [Chapter 3 Administering Domains](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggnop/index.html) for more asadmin commands.

Comment: just to be more clear. On linux the asadmin is launched be the command
`./asadmin` not  `asadmin`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the valid "asadmin start-domain" & stop-domain option already given, you can utilize operating system services to start/stop GlassFish, much like you do with your PHP environment.

Look into "asadmin create-service" command:

$ asadmin create-service --help

You can also check out the documentation on docs.oracle.com on how to create a service with create-service.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd [GlassFishHome]/bin
asadmin stop-domain domain1
```